# Elasticsearch: How much better read-only performance is 2 or 3 zones vs 1 zone?

Tags: elasticsearch

If you are not indexing anything, I would have suspected that having three zones of an es cluster should be roughly the same performance as having three one-zone es clusters that shared the work. Is this thinking correct or am I misunderstanding how zones work? I understand the primary benefit of dual-zone is availability, just wondering if it 'doubles' or 'triples' performance for read-only processes at the same time!

Comment: what do you mean by zones here in your context?

Comment: The correct term is “availability zones”

Answer (score 0):

After looking at performance by randomly assigning requests to two clusters, one with 2 zones, another with 1 zone, the difference in performance is non-existent.

This is performance with 2 zones.
[image]

This is performance with 1 zones.
[image]

Comment: I wonder why ES would not allocate requests between the two zones to improve performance. I'm sure there's a very good reason for this

Comment: In hindsight, perhaps this is because I didn't create a replica set?